Cannot bind to 0.0.0.0 in C# / Docker (no ASP!)
I try to open a port from a console application in C# that runs in a docker container. I believe that the underlying issue is that I cannot bind to 0.0.0.0:1234. In order to demonstrate the issue I will share a simple web server. I receive the error message

System.Net.HttpListenerException: 'The request is not supported.'

when running the following code:
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

string html = "<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>";

HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://0.0.0.0:1234/");
//listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:1234/");

listener.Start();

while (true)
{
    HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
    HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;

    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);
    response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;

    Stream output = response.OutputStream;
    output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    output.Close();
}

I run the code using the VS 2022 integrated docker facilities. My Dockerfile looks like this:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:8.0 AS base
EXPOSE 1234
USER app
WORKDIR /app

[...]

And my docker-compose.yml:
services:
  demo:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}demo
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: demo/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "1234:1234"

What can I do to access my container from the browser at http://localhost:1234?
Things that I tried:
I executed the code on my host (no docker involved) and here it worked when binding to localhost:1234.
I tried binding to localhost:1234 when hosting in the docker container. No error occurs but the browser tells me that the server seems not to be up.
I checked that the mapping worked when binding to localhost:1234 (which then lead me to the conclusion that I should bind to 0.0.0.0:1234).
docker port demo_1
1234/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:1234

I tried a couple of ports (80, 8080, finally 1234) in order to not conflict with some pre-defined configuration from the image.
I tried to find some documentation on potential environment variables but all you find out there appears to be related to ASP.

Docker containers have their own virtual network configuration. Try changing your listener to the following so it will bind to any IP address and allow all HTTP methods:
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:1234/");

Then you should be able to access your container on the host with:
http://localhost:1234

Thanks :-) In a more complex scenario where the container might be part of multiple virtual networks this might not be appropriate if I don't want to expose on all IPs. Is there a way to identify the "right" IP address?

You would need to get the container's IP address for a specific network. A docker container gets a different IP address on each connected virtual network. Then you could bind to this IP address.
